# changing parent theme into child theme

Tags: child-theme

I inherited a site that didn't use a child theme, and now it needs to be updated. Can I take the original parent theme, change the style sheet header, copy it into the root, delete everything but wp-content and make it be the child theme? In the past, I've loaded any files I wanted from the parent into the child theme, and it is my understanding that the browser will prefer whatever's in the child theme.

Answer (score -2):

That is 100% the approach you should take. You can even set up the child theme with a folder `your-child-theme-name/` and then a style.css which uses the parent as the template:

```
template: your-parent-theme-folder
```

Then, you can either import the styles into this style.css (`@import url('../parent-theme-folder/style.css')`) or start from scratch as needed.

You'll also be able to pull in files you want to edit (like header.php or footer.php).

Additional reading:

- https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/01/create-customize-wordpress-child-theme/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/
- https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-create-wordpress-child-theme

Comment: thank you, I'm not sure you're addressing my question specifically, which is, can I literally  rename the current parent as -child, and load up a fresh, updated copy of the parent. To simplify I would remove anything from now what is the child that wasn't altered originally. i was just wondering if anyone had done that.

Comment: My apologies, I completely missed the point of your question! You are absolutely correct, you can do that. Again, my apologies for confusing issues here.

Comment: no problem and thanks!

Comment: When did child themes stop becoming best practice? I'm trying to brush up on the last 9 years.